# div overriding positioning?

Tags: html, css

Is there any way to prevent the main_wrapper from overlapping the footer? the footer has to maintain and position: absolute so that it stays flushed at the bottom of the browser.

```
#page_contain {
    min-height: 100%;
    position: relative;
}

#main_wrapper {
    width: 950px;
    height: 800px;
    margin: 0 auto 25px auto;
    position: relative;
    border: 1px solid #000;
}

#footer {
    position:absolute;
    bottom: 0;
    width: 100%;
    height: 60px;
    text-align: center;
    font-family: Verdana;
}
```

html

```
<div id="page_contain"></div>
<div id="main_wrapper"></div>
<div id="footer">
line 1 <br />
line 2 <br />
line 2 <br />
line 2 <br />
line 2 <br />
line 2 <br />
</div>
```

Comment: I really think one would have to see HTML to answer this question.

Comment: @RichardJPLeGuen Not really, they're just div's the content of the divs shouldn't matter. the problem can be duplicated with 3 empty divs with the set id's

Comment: Ok, but where are they in the HTML document? Which one comes first or second or last? Are there other non-statically positioned elements involved?

Comment: @RichardJPLeGuen i've added some sample html code

Answer (score 2):

A better way to approach this problem is to apply a fixed positioning to the footer so that it is always at the bottom of the screen.  Here's your code in jsfiddle:

http://jsfiddle.net/bnryh/

Answer (score 1):

Apply the `z-index` property to your footer:

```
#footer{
    [...]
    z-index: 50;
}
```

Comment: didn't work still overlaps... example, you may have to increase main_wrapper height to 900 depending on browsers size.
<div id="page_contain"></div>
<div id="main_wrapper"></div>
<div id="footer">sdsdsdsdsdsdsdsdssdsd</div>

Comment: Works fine for me. Infact it works fine even without the z-index due to the natural document flow.

Comment: There must be something else you're doing.

Comment: are you filling in some lines... ? my screen is pretty big so even at 900px i don't see an overlap but if i set my browser to redender at 800px height i see the overlap

Comment: can you show me your example of it working? I just did a basic empty div and it did not work

Comment: Here's a very simple example showing the footer rendering above the main content area: http://jsfiddle.net/2TUqH/

Answer (score 0):

```
#page_contain {
    min-height: 100%;
    position: relative;
}
#main_wrapper {
    width: 950px;
    height: 100%;
    margin: 0 auto 25px auto;
    position: relative;
    border: 1px solid #000;
    padding-bottom:100px;
}
#footer {
    clear:both;
    position:absolute;
    bottom: 0;
    width: 100%;
    height: 60px;
    text-align: center;
    font-family: Verdana;
}
```